# Restore parts of Postgres database dump

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have two databases, `db1` and `db2`. They're not identical but do share some tables, `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

I have dumped `d1` to dump1.sql, and now I want to restore `t1`, `t2` and `t3` of that dump to `d2`. What would be the best way for me to do this?

Comment: Use `pg_dump -Fc` to create a custom-format dump, perhaps with `-t` options to dump only some tables. Then use `pg_restore`, perhaps again with `-t`, to restore only some tables. You cannot easily extract tables from a SQL format dump, you should always use custom-format dumps.

Comment: ex: `pg_dump -t '(t1|t2|t3)'` will take backup of only t1,t2 and t3 tables